# Confluence links view permission

Tags: user-permissions, confluence, wiki-markup

I'm using Confluence 4.1.4 and want links to spaces and pages to be visible to anybody, even if the user hasn't got view permission for the target.

This is the code:

```
<ac:link><ri:space ri:space-key="FOO" /><ac:plain-text-link-body>Bar</ac:plain-text-link-body></ac:link>
```

The user won't see "Bar" but only FOO. IMHO it would be even better not to display the link at all.

Is there a workaround that displays the page title (without using an exotic plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (ugly) workaround in our case is to treat the links as external links.

Answer (score 2):

In Confluence 4.3 the text of the links (e.g. page title) is visible for users who 
doesn't have view permission for the target.

I don't know in which version this introduces.

Comment: Good to know, but we currently can't upgrade. Any workaround for 4.1.4?

Comment: Not of any i can think of. Except using Plugins (Visibility PLugin)